# Creating a common header for an android app

Tags: android, performance, header, memory-management

I am looking to create a common header for an android activity and have 3 possible ways to solve the same. I would like to know which is the best solution in terms of performance and memory usage.

1. Copy the XML across all XML Layouts : I believe this is the least impressive solution which uses a lot of memory
2. Create a custom HeaderView , which I can then use where needed. Drawbacks : it still creates a lot of instances.
3. Use `<include >` to include an XML component , not sure how it helps performance and reduces memory usage.

So which method is the best , or is there a better way?

Comment: @jleedev How would one use fragments for this?

Comment: I’m not quite sure, but they might allow you to reuse a bit of layout with a single element. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are worrying about the wrong thing. Pick the one that's best for your project with regards to development or maintainability. Remember that Views are all part of ONE activity which would be visible to the user at any time, per the Android activity lifecycle. Its the framework's responsibility to clean up non-visible activities if there is a need to garbage collect. If you are concerned about View performance, look into using [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) which comes with the SDK to flatten your views.

Answer (score 1):

The third way looks like a good candidate... the performance difference among all ways of doing it is not big. On the other hand, the maintainability difference it's. So, the third options allows a cleaner solution since you won't have boilerplate code, and will allow you to easily change the header in the future without having to modify the other views.

The second solution is nice, but it introduces unnecessary complexity. Are you going to use more than three activities with that header? Are you going to share that `HeaderView` or reuse it in other project? If no... then it's not worthy. Even worse, it will make you write Java code, which is less maintainable than a few lines of XML.

Comment: what about memory usage of the include tag, does Android add an instance for every include?

Comment: @Ravi Since XML layouts are preprocessed, i consider them being a better option creating a layout. The 1st and the 3rd options are best, but since 3rd options is more maintanable. i Would go with the 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I would go for the 3rd one although its make no difference in terms of memory but it will make the code more cleaner at-least for xml. I might be wrong but thats just my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using step 2 and setting my header object to null in onPause and resetting it in onResume , that way the garbage collector could free up the resource. Thanks @Morrison Chang :-)